# How to select N random groups within a table

Tags: mysql, sql

My groups are split across rows like so:

```
   Row  Group
   1    A
   2    A
   3    A
   4    B
   5    B
   6    C
   7    C
   8    C
   9    C
```

How can I select all rows for any 2 randomly chosen groups?

Comment: Select "any 2 randomly chosen groups" in subquery and INNER JOIN it to another copy of your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort random, pick 2 groups.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table AS t
WHERE `Group` IN (
  SELECT `Group` FROM (
    SELECT `Group`
      FROM your_table
      GROUP BY `Group`
      ORDER BY RAND()
      LIMIT 2) q);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=bdfbb4729b8d165f6bab65037ec1e4c9)*

Answer (score 0):

To select rows of any two groups

```
select * 
from t_groups
group by Group
having Group in ['A', 'B'];
```

To randomly select any two groups

```
select * 
from t_groups
group by Group
having Group in (
SELECT Group FROM t_groups
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2);
```